# rm -rf all files and all hidden files without . & .. error

Tags: wildcards, rm

`rm -rf /some/path/*` deletes all non-hidden files in that dir (and subdirs).

`rm -rf /some/path/.*` deletes all hidden files in that dir (but not subdirs) and also gives the following error/warning:

```
rm: cannot remove directory: `/some/dir/.'
rm: cannot remove directory: `/some/dir/..'
```

What is the proper way to remove all hidden and non-hidden files and folders recursively in a target directory without receiving the warning/error about `.` and `..`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could always send error messages to `/dev/null`

```
rm -rf /some/path/.* 2> /dev/null
```

You could also just

```
rm -rf /some/path/
mkdir /some/path/
```

...then you won't have to bother with hidden files in the first place.

Comment: But what if I only want to delete the hidden files?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai that should be a different question, but you can find the solution in Gilles' answer (`rm ..?* .[!.]*` should do it).

Comment: Doesn't deleting and recreating the directory pose the risk that the file permissions are not right afterwards (especially important in server environments). Who could one create the folder with the same permissions as before automatically?

Comment: @YoLudke You are absolutely correct, in many situations it doesn't matter but deleting the folder and recreating is not semantically equivalent to emptying that folder; so be careful doing that!

Comment: Deleting the directory is not always possible. In my case the directory is a docker volume, and while i can do whatever I want inside the volume, i cant change the volume itself from within the container.

Answer (score 180):

`*` matches all non-dot-files, `.[!.]*` matches all dot files except `.` and files whose name begins with `..`, and `..?*` matches all dot-dot files except `..`. Together they match all files other than `.` and `..`. If any of these three patterns matches nothing, it expands to itself; `rm -f` doesn't care about non-existent arguments, so this doesn't matter.

```
rm -rf -- ..?* .[!.]* *
```

You can also use `find`. This is more complex but has the advantage of working even if there are so many files that the wildcards above would expand beyond your system's command line length limit.

```
find . -name . -o -prune -exec rm -rf -- {} +
```

You may find it clearer to remove and recreate the directory. This has the advantage (or downside, as the case may be) of resulting in an empty directory even if another program is concurrently creating files in the original directory.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it prevents parent traversal and possible deletion.

Comment: The `find` alternative returns "success" even if some file is not successfully deleted; not good for script.

Comment: With regards to your second `find` command, the manpage for find states "Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together." -- yet you use `-prune -delete`?

Comment: @DoktorJ Indeed, `-prune` doesn't do anything here. And on reading back I see that I didn't answer the question correctly: I took care not to recurse, but the question explicitly asks for recursive deletion. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I'd find `find . ! -name . -prune -exec rm -rf {} +` less confusing (even if  strictly equivalent)

Comment: Very nice, but your globbing is bash-specific, though (which the question isn't).

Comment: @haylem Nothing in this answer is specific to bash.

Comment: @Gilles: Maybe, my bad. I should have said that zsh refuses this syntax.

Comment: @haylem In zsh, you need to write `.[^.]*` instead of `.[!.]*` when history substitution is enabled (which by default is the case interactively but not in scripts), because zsh parses `!` as a history reference. But in zsh you wouldn't need that in the first place, you can just use `*(D)` to include dot files (without `.` or `..`) in the wildcard match.

Comment: I've tried the `find` approach: `find . -name . -o -prune -exec rm -rf -- {} +`. Is it trying to delete everything in my current directory?!! `rm: cannot remove './hobby/outdoors/RACCC WW Beginners Handbook 2016 Final.docx': Permission denied`

Comment: @sakovias Yes, it's trying to delete everything in your current directory, including subdirectories. That was the whole point. Of course, it's limited by permissions. If some files can't be deleted, it'll only delete the ones that can be.,

Comment: `rm -rf /path/to/subdirectory/{..?*,.[!.]*,*} 2>/dev/null`

Comment: I am using zsh: I tried `rm -rf /home/user/somedir/{,.[^.],..?}*`  and i got `zsh: no matches found: /home/user/somedir/..?*` . Then @Gillies i tried `rm -rf /home/user/somedir/*(D)` and it worked `*(D) to include dot files (without . or ..) in the wildcard match`

Comment: This perhaps simpler: `find /repo -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -r -- {} +`. `-mindepth` to prevent deleting the given directory, `-maxdepth` to avoid stuff that's already going to be deleted by `rm -r`

Comment: Is there an actual risk that `rm -rf .*` does parent traversal? In any flavour of UNIX?

Comment: @TorstenBronger Not in any modern flavor, I think. They refuse to recurse over `..` so they'll only delete children of the current directory. But I wouldn't put it past some older implementations of `rm` to omit this check and therefore delete the current directory and its siblings before they try and fail to `rmdir("..")`.

Comment: Also worth noting that using `./*` or `-- *` would be safer in case a filename starts with a dash (`-`) so that it doesn't get interpreted as an option.

Answer (score 39):

Just realised this is the most convenient way in most Linux distros:

```
ls -A1 | xargs rm -rf
```

where

`-A` = list everything **except** `.` and `..`

`-1` = put every item in one line

Comment: downside which I see is: you need to 'cd' into directory to do this.

Comment: `ls -A1 /your/path/ | xargs rm -rf` should apply

Comment: nope..it does not help - For example: ls -A1 ~/test/ | xargs rm -rf   this command deletes files which I am currently 'cd into'..not in the directory ~/test.

Comment: It doesn't work if any of the file names contain blanks, newlines, quotes or backslashes.

Comment: Yeah @StéphaneChazelas, that's why `xargs` is awful.

Comment: If there is blank inside filename, it will be split into multiple file names. So this command is better `ls -A1 | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}`

Comment: @QiLuo ...unless the blank is a newline, or unless a filename begins with `-`.

Answer (score 28):

Either change the `dotglob` option of your shell and use `*`, or use something like `find`.

```
find somedir -mindepth 1 -delete
```

Comment: Or you could simply `rm -rf /some/dir` and then create a new empty directory in its place.

Comment: @tripleee, in such case permissions might differ in the result.

Comment: Sure, there are scenarios where you can't recreate it exactly if it didn't belong to you in the first place even though you had write permissions. But in most real-life scenarios all you need is check the permissions so you can set them back to what they were.

Comment: Any downsides to this? Curious as to why this is not the top answer...

Answer (score 11):

This should work just like [@Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77313/133353) answer but more compact:

```
rm -rf {,.[!.],..?}*
```

or

```
rm -rf dir/to/files/{,.[!.],..?}*
```

should also add an `if` for usage in scripts just to be safe:

```
if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    rm -rf ${DIR}/{,.[!.],..?}*
fi
```

Comment: Oddly enough, as a bash alias on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the previous answer wasn't working.  However, `alias cleandir='rm -rf {,.[!.],..?}*'` does.

Comment: @StevenVentimiglia Interactions with `!` and history? What shell?

Comment: Flippin heck - NO.  
Do not ever write rm -rf $x/.....  
It $x evaluates to empty you will delete a whole lot more than you want to. And believe me, and some point, now or later, it WILL be empty.  
just find another way - do a cd to $DIR like:  
`if cd $DIR    # NO TRAILING SLASH  
then  
       if [ "/" != "$(pwd)" ]  
           rm -rf ./

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you experiment with

Turn-**ON** *dots* (hidden files)

- set `dotglob`

  `shopt -s dotglob`

Turn-**OFF** *dots*

- unset `dotglob`

  `shopt -u dotglob`

This method worked exactly as I *wished* for a ***copy*** command that was missing the hidden directories.

```
    shopt -s    dotglob
    cp    -rvn  ./$from/*  ./$too/
    shopt -u    dotglob
```

So I did a remove (delete), and *oops* ...

```
    shopt -s    dotglob
    rm -fr ../message_splitter--044a/*
    shopt -u    dotglob
```

... *that works too!*

It occurs to me that *you* dear reader can't see the `message_splitter` directory.  Any way it has a `.svn` folder that needs to be removed, and copied Into.

*From `man` page* ...

> `dotglob`  If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results of pathname expansion.

references:

- [recursively cp all directories, files and hidden files](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/recursively-cp-all-directories-files-and-hidden-files-808403/) ([linuxquestions.org](https://www.linuxquestions.org), *accessed*: 2018-May-09)

Comment: Behaviour of `shopt` [is unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01).  This answer may be useful for a subset of shells, but you didn't specify which ones.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the proper way to remove all hidden and non-hidden files and folders recursively in a target directory without receiving the warning/error about . and ..?

Assuming the directory in question is `./dir`, then

```
rm -rf ./dir
```

would remove all files in `./dir`, including hidden files and directories, recursively, and including the `./dir` directory itself.

If you do not want to delete the directory itself, then you may just recreate it afterwards, or use

```
find ./dir -mindepth 1 -delete
```

or if you `find` does not support `-delete`,

```
find ./dir -mindepth 1 -depth -exec rm -rf {} ';'
```

Using `-mindepth 1` allows you to keep the top-level directory `./dir`.

Comment: Note, if the directory itself is the mount point for a filesystem, eg `/mnt/usbmemorystick` (if your goal is to delete all the files on a filesystem), then you can't just delete that directory itself.

Comment: @CraigMcQueen In that case the speediest alternative may be to unmount the file system, recreate it, and mount it again.

Comment: Possibly, although that comes with its own set of challenges, such as making sure to recreate the filesystem with the same parameters. Some filesystems have some subtle parameters. Eg for ext4, the inode size, with consequences for Y2038 compatibility.

Comment: The `rm` suggestion also breaks if dir is a symlink, or if the directory has non-default permissions, ACLs, etc.

Comment: @ChrisDavies Are you referring to `rm -rf ./dir`? I thought it was given that we were talking about a _directory_. Also, the permissions on the parent directory of `dir` may come into play, that's true, but if `dir` disallowed removal of contents, then you would obviously need to `chmod` it to be able to remove _anything_ inside it (the question indicates that this is no issue).  The only issue with not being allowed to remove `dir` itself is that you don't have to recreate it later :-P  I'm not a Linux user, so I'll leave the ACL, SELinux and other weirdness to you guys :-)

Answer (score 4):

Find is your friend.

```
find ! -name '.' ! -name '..' -delete

% find ! -name '.' ! -name '..'
./test
./test4
./test4/.test6
./test3
./.test5
./test2
% find ! -name '.' ! -name '..' -delete    
% find ! -name '.' ! -name '..'     
%
```

If you wish to use recursively search something other your current directory ($PWD), then add a path right after the `find` command; e.g., `find /path ! -name '.' ! -name '..' -delete`.  If you only want to descend `n` number of directories, then use the `-maxdepth n` option right after the `/path` parameter.

The above command was tested on an Ubuntu 13.04 system.  Will likely work on other, modern linux systems.

Comment: to delete all directories in the current directory you could do ```find . ! -name '.' ! -name '..' -type d -delete```

Answer (score 4):

Why nobody mentions:

```
rm -rf * .*
```

Comment: Because this gives the same warnings that the user in the question wants to avoid.

Comment: Oh my bad. But this is the shortest one line to get the thing done.

Comment: Indeed, except that it doesn't answer the question as asked

Answer (score 0):

What about using find with both -maxdepth and -mindepth?
This can be also run outside the directory you want to clear.

```
find target/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec rm -fr -- {} +;
```

Here's a complete example:

```bsh
mkdir -p target/{plain{0..3},.hidden{0..3}}; 
touch target/{plain{0..3},.hidden{0..3}} target/{plain{0..3},.hidden{0..3}}/{plain{0..3},.hidden{0..3}};
tree -a;
find target/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec rm -fr -- {} +;
tree -a;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Shorter version

```
rm -r * .*
```

`rm`: remove

`-r`: recursively

`*`: all directories

`.*`: all hidden directories ( ex: .git, .gitignore )

use an optional force flag ( `--force` or `-f` ). Check the usage [here](https://blog.purestorage.com/purely-technical/when-to-use-the-force-flag-in-linux/#:%7E:text=What%20Is%20the%20%2Df%20Flag,necessary%20for%20applications%20to%20function.).

```
rm -rf * .*
```

**Note: ( for zsh users )**
The above command doesn't work partially i.e If it can't find files/ directories matching any of `*` or `.*` the other one won't execute.

You can fix this using the command

```
setopt no_nomatch
```

zsh commands are scoped to a session(/tab). ( if you open a new session you will still face the issue ).

add this line to `.zshrc` file to apply for all sessions.

ps: restart iterm after making changes to `.zshrc`

Comment: You forgot to explain how this avoids the warnings for `.` and `..`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I used the command recently, it didn't give any warning that was mentioned in the question. Should I add this?

Answer (score 0):

the find command of the other answer did not work for me as it tries to remove the directory itself. I found this one works better:

```bash
remove() {
  find "$1" ! -name "$1" -a -prune -exec rm -rfv -- {} +
}

remove foobar
```

Note, you must *not* include a / at the end of the directory, otherwise it will try to remove the directory as well.

You can use `-wholename` instead of `-name` if your path starts with `/`.

The `v` of the `rm` command prints out the files as they are being deleted.