# rm wildcard not working

Tags: bash, shell, rm, dot-files

I want to delete all `.swp` files recursively. However:

```
rm -r *.swp
```

Gives:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘*.swp’: No such file or directory
```

Just to be sure, `ls -all` gives:

```
total 628
drwxr--r--.  8 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 18:16 .
drwxr--r--. 31 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 18:14 ..
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 przecze przecze    108 Jul 28 21:41 build.sh
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 przecze przecze 298617 Aug  3 00:52 exec
drwxr--r--.  8 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 18:08 .git
drwxrwxr-x.  2 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 18:14 inc
-rw-rw-r--.  1 przecze przecze    619 Aug  3 00:52 main.cc
-rw-r--r--.  1 przecze przecze  12288 Aug  3 17:29 .main.cc.swp
-rw-rw-r--.  1 przecze przecze    850 Aug  1 00:30 makefile
-rw-------.  1 przecze przecze 221028 Aug  3 01:47 nohup.out
drwxrwxr-x.  2 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 00:52 obj
drwxrwxr-x.  2 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 00:52 out
drwxrwxr-x. 12 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 18:14 runs
-rwxr--r--.  1 przecze przecze  23150 Aug  2 18:56 Session.vim
drwxrwxr-x.  2 przecze przecze   4096 Aug  3 18:14 src
-rw-rw-r--.  1 przecze przecze  13868 Jul 31 19:28 tags
-rw-rw-r--.  1 przecze przecze   2134 Aug  3 00:31 view.py
-rw-r--r--.  1 przecze przecze  12288 Aug  3 17:29 .view.py.swp
```

So there are `*.swp` files to delete! And `rm .build.sh.swp` successfully deleted one of them. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By default *glob* patterns do not match files starting with dot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to match the dot:

```
$ rm -r .*.swp
```

I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it worked! And I already found out, that simple `.swp` does not match dot-files -[link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77127/rm-rf-all-files-and-all-hidden-files-without-error) . Thanks!

Comment: You should not need superuser privileges to delete files that you own.  `rm -r` is dangerous, though, I would suggest `rm -i .*.swp` or `find . -type f -name .\*.swp`, confirming the list of files and following up with `find . -type f -name .\*.swp -delete`

Comment: @DopeGhoti, to be able to delete a file, you need write permission to the directory it is linked to. Whether you own the file is only relevant for files in directories that you don't own and have the `t` bit set. Here, it looks like the OP owns and has write access to the directory, so there shouldn't be any permission issue. The `.` after the permissions suggests however that maybe there are additional security mechanisms at play that could get in the way.

Comment: This does not delete `.swp` files recursively. The glob pattern expands to all `.*.swp` in the current directory, but not subdirectories. The `rm` command only sees the expanded file names. To delete recursively, I suggest using `find` piped to `xargs`.

Answer (score 4):

It's `Bash` feature controlled by `dotglob` shell option described in `man page`:

> If set, bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results
>   of pathname expansion.

As it's a `Bash` feature it causes other commands such as `grep`, `ls`
etc. do not handle files starting with `.` if dotglob is not set as
well. You can check if `dotglob` is set on your system using shopt
built-in, it must be `off` if you experience such issues:

```
$ shopt | grep dotglob
dotglob         off
```

If `shopt` was set `*` would match *all* files, even these starting
with `.`. See this example:

```
$ touch a b c .d
$ ls *
a  b  c
$ ls *d
ls: cannot access '*d': No such file or directory
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ shopt | grep dotglob
dotglob         on
$ ls *
.d  a  b  c
$ ls *d
.d
```

When `dotglob` is off you can still create a pattern to handle files
in the current dir together with hidden files:

```
ls .[!.]* *
```

or

```
ls .[^.]* *
```