# Remove files/folders that start with "."

Tags: bash, rm, dot-files

This command:

```
rm -rf "$HOME/.quicklock/locks/"*
```

does seem to remove files or folders in the locks directory, which start with "."

how can I remove those files too? Any other filenames that would fail to be removed given that command?

Comment: Alexander, should the Q read “does *not* seem to remove...”?

Comment: If you want to remove everything, why not `rm -rf "$HOME/.quicklock/lock" && mkdir $HOME/.quicklock/lock`?

Comment: @tachomi that's probably the right idea lol, but maybe some race conditions if the dir does not exist, but I can handle that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clever combination of wildcards to avoid `.` and `..`:

```
rm -fr .??*
```

would be one of them, which works if you don't have any files or directories that are only 2 characters long (like `.x` for example).

```
rm -fr .[!.]*
```

does that job better.

Comment: Would miss a directory or file named `.X`, unfortunately.

Comment: Huh, that *is* unexpected. And ".X" seems to be specifically the issue. Longer filenames are no trouble...

Comment: each question mark requires a character....

Comment: Okay that makes more sense... the .??* is something I came up with years ago and to which I never gave any more thought. To be fair, I never had to deal with 2-character file/directory names. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77127/rm-rf-all-files-and-all-hidden-files-without-error/313388), and updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got a suggestion to do this:

```
rm -rf "$HOME/.quicklook/locks";
mkdir -p "$HOME/.quicklock/locks";
```

should work, I guess.

Comment: of course invites race conditions if other processes expect `"$HOME/.quicklock/locks"` to always exist, but nothing that mkdir -p can't solve if I just use that command elsewhere.

Comment: SO and SE Unix/Linux is not a forum board where you go and add a comment on previous comment it works like question and answers kind of thinkg

Comment: sorry I don't follow...I add comments to my answers all the time